# Laravel Schedule creates a file for every call to a command

Tags: laravel, schedule

I have created a schedule with Laravel and after some struggle I managed to get it working but the problem now is that for every call to the a command it creates a file inside the laravel folder and they are getting pilled up.

I am using this command at the crontab to keep it running:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I guess I need to use some options to prevent it from output. Any idea?

Comment: What is the name of the file which is generated?

Comment: They are the same name as the commands and some of the with an extension of a digit. for example mycommand.1